# How to get pairs of brace expansions without getting all combinations?

Tags: bash, unix, snakemake

I work on macOS High Sierra 10.13.3. My shell is bash.

When I type, `echo {1,2}{3,4}`

I get: `13 14 23 24`.

Is there an option to get `13 24` only?

I am interested in creating many files where two locations in a file vary together. For example, I want the files:

`file1file1`
`file2file2`
`file3file3`

It would be convenient to write something like `file{1,2,3}file{1,2,3} option` instead of `file1file1 file2file2 file3file3`.

I would like to be able to use this expansion in a command, such as:

`touch file{1,2,3}file{1,2,3} option` to create three files.

I hope that the functionality I am looking for is clear.

#### Clarification

Ultimately, the context I want to use this functionality in is with a snakemake command:

`snakemake --cores 3 release{42,43,44}/file{42,43,44}.txt`

where I want snakemake to produce the files release42/file42.txt, release43/file43.txt and release44/file44.txt.

If I use a loop to achieve this, the files will be produced in succession. However, by typing `snakemake release42/file42.txt release43/file43.txt release44/file44.txt`, the three files will be produced simultaneously. However, as I am lazy, I want to type something shorter than `snakemake release42/file42.txt release43/file43.txt release44/file44.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get 13 14 do

```
$ echo 1{3,4}
```

for the duplicates, there are other ways

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do printf "file%dfile%d " $i $i; done
file1file1 file2file2 file3file3
```

to use with `touch`

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do touch "file${i}file${i}"; done
```

or, using all filenames at once

```
$ touch $(for i in {1..3}; do printf "file%dfile%d " $i $i; done)
```

Comment: for the 13 14, I made a mistake in my question, sorry. Regarding your other answer, it's printing it but I'd like to be able to use this in a command, to create the files for example.

Comment: how is `echo` command creating files?  Not sure I got what you mean.  `printf` is just more powerful `echo`.

Comment: I've made my question more precise by adding what I want to do with the `touch` command.

Comment: I understand I could use a for loop with this as well, but to create many files, I think it would be more efficient to expand braces to create them all at once. Furthermore, I need this functionality in another context (launching a snakemake command), where I would like all output files in one command.

Comment: added more details about what I want to achieve in the clarification.

Comment: The last approach with the unquoted expansion is fragile. Any filename with spaces -> boom. (Safe for this specific case where we control all characters in the output with sane values for IFS, but better to describe the limitations of a potentially-harmful practice when showcasing it so it doesn't get applied outside that limited safe scope).

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop to form an array.

```
items=( )
for i in {42,43,44}; do
  items+=( "release$i/file$i.txt" )
done

snakemake "${items[@]}"
```

This runs `snakemake` only once, with all the files listed.

Comment: Tweak: `s/{42,43,44}/4{2..4}/`.